# Can the cup-product of non-zero cohomology classes be zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading a text that seems to be assuming that if $u, v \in H^1(X, R)$ are non-zero cohomology classes for a given topological space $X$ and ring $R$, then the cup-product $u \cup v $ is non-zero in $H^2(X, R)$. Most of the knowledge of cup-products I have is due to the same text, so I lack the intuition to even guess if this is right or wrong, even worst to (dis)prove this.

Comment: This is not true. Just take $X$ to be a space with $H^1(X, R) \neq 0$ and $H^2(X, R) = 0$, e.g. $X = S^1$. What is the text you are reading and what makes you think that this assumption is being made?

Comment: Very nice, thanks. There is some simple example like that shows that the statement is still false if we require $H^2(X,R)$ to be non-zero? I believe the author will use in such context.

Comment: Sure, $X = S^1\times S^2$.

Comment: It can even be different within the same space. Inside the cohomology algebra of the torus $(S^1)^n$ (over any ring) we have $\alpha\cup\alpha=0$ but $\alpha\cup\beta\neq0$ for generators $\alpha,\beta$ of the first cohomology

Comment: The intuition is that the cup product counts the intersections of [geometric representatives of] the dual homology classes, and of course those might not intersect at all.

Comment: If $u \in H^1(X;R)$, then $2 (u \cup u) = 0$, so if $H^2(X;R)$ has no 2-torsion then $u \cup u = 0$. That will give lots of examples.